# use pdf.js web viewer without node_module dependencies

Tags: javascript, svn, pdf.js

I cloned and built [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) using `gulp generic` command. I intend to use the viewer located in `/web/viewer.html` , but the scripts requires `node_modules` dependencies.

Is there a way to build pdf.js to use this viewer without the `node_module` dependencies ? i work on an SVN environment and i can't add the `node_modules` folder to the versioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use web/viewer.html for production. Since you already run `gulp generic` -- use viewer in build/generic/web/viewer.html and it does not have dependencies in node_modules. ... or you can just download this part from http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download

Comment: As a Wordpress dev I don't have node.js. This package had viewer.html which is what I wanted. My client just wants pdfs embedded without download links etc. The pdfs are copyrighted but theft is not the end of the world. Just doesn't want the pdfs downloaded by default. Pdf.js is whole world and I don't even want to know about it.

Comment: And also make sure you set HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS